# Appcelerator - font arabic IOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I use font Arabic in my project using Appcelerator titanium, that's work perfectly on Android, but not on IOS.

This seems to be a bug in iOS !! Is there any solution on Appcelerator !!

[image]

class of font

```
".fontRegular": {
  font: {
    fontFamily: "HsnRazan-Regular"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please so some code ?

Comment: How did you try to set the font?

Comment: i added some code @Surajkochale

Comment: i added some code @RobinEllerkmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS you have to use the font's PostScript name.

To find a font's PostScript name on OS X:

- Open FontBook.
- Select the desired font from the list.
- Press Cmd+I to view the PostScript name for the font.

Example:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts-section-29004935_CustomFonts-Findingafont%27sPostScriptname

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/images/download/attachments/29004935/postscript-name.png

Comment: Ideally you'd use the PostScript name as the file name so you can use the same `fontFamily` value for both iOS and Android.